# Spring - Repository from other Jar is null. How to initialize it?

Tags: spring, gradle, spring-data

I  have a project that does data access in one project and  to use it in another project as `spring` jar. I created jar using `gradle maven-publish` plugin. I initialized this Jar in my other project test case like this

```
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"classpath*:spring-config.xml"})
@Transactional
public class TenantProvisioningManagerTest extends AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests {}
```

Class where `Repository` is being used. I used like this

```
public class TenantProvisioningManager {

    private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(TenantProvisioningManager.class);

    @Autowired
    TProductRepository tProductRepository;
}
```

Repository is `null` here. How to initialize repository from other jar in this seperate project?

`spring-config.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
              http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
              http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
              http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
              http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
              http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
              http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa
              http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa.xsd
              ">
<context:property-placeholder
        location="file://#{systemEnvironment['GRADLE_USER_HOME']}/gradle.properties"/>
<!-- the base package for spring data jpa repository interfaces -->
<jpa:repositories base-package="com.asklytics.dao.repos" />

<!-- Enable the component scan (auto wiring etc) for the following package -->
<context:component-scan base-package="com.asklytics" />

<!-- Make sure the following is specified to enable transaction  -->
<tx:annotation-driven />
<bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager" id="transactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
</bean>

<!--  This defines the entity manager factory with some custom properties -->
<bean id='entityManagerFactory' class='org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean'>
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="persitanceUnit"/>
    <property name='dataSource' ref='dataSource' />
</bean>

<bean id='dataSource' class='org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource'>
    <property name='driverClassName' value='com.mysql.jdbc.Driver' />
    <property name='url' value="${awsCamelDbUrl}" />
    <property name='username' value="${awsCamelDbUsername}" />
    <property name='password' value="${awsCamelDbPassword}" />
</bean>
```

`spring-config.xml` and `TProductRepository` are in other project while `TenantProvisioningManager` is in seperate project.

Comment: Do you have spring-data-jpa on the classpath, and is your spring config scanning the package where these repositories exist? Also, the fact that it's `null` rather than throwing an `NoSuchBeanDefinitionException` probably means that your `TenantProvisioningManager` isn't being managed by Spring, so your autowiring is broken.

Comment: Yes spring-data-jpa is on class path. How can I confirm about scanning the package? How can I make `TenantProvisioningManager` being managed by Spring?

Comment: Post the content of `spring-config.xml`.  Also, what packages are `TenantProvisioningManager` and `TProductRepository` in?

Comment: @manish added the `spring-config.xml`.

Comment: I feel silly even bringing this up, but I will since I don't see code for TProductRepository. Is the jar in question a jar you wrote and compiled yourself? If so, is TProductRepository annotated with @Repository?

Comment: Show the entire class where you're using the `TenantProvisioningManager`.

Comment: All of this seems alright.  Hopefully you don't have multiple files named `spring-config.xml` on the classpath?  It will also be useful to turn on debug logging and checking that `spring-config.xml` is indeed being picked up.

Comment: One thing, the spring xml which you include: classpath:spring-config.xml, can you check in the jar you compiled is it present there? Otherwise why don't you manually put this file in your current project (i.e outside the jar) to see if that is causing the issue?

Comment: can you share please your pom.xml? I suspect that you don't have spring-web or spring-webmvc on your classpath. or that you have collision between jars(diffrent versions of spring).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure your `TenantProvisioningManager` is also managed by spring. Annotate is as @Component